# My C code gives no error in compilation or runtime but segfaults using gdb

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I started programming in C 2 weeks ago (sorry if code is cringe).

I was trying to make a text editor in Windows 11. I stored the text in a char* with a global variable storing the size of text. This gives me the result just as I want, but as soon as I try to put both the size and char* in a struct the code doesn't output anything at all. Here is the code (the one with struct implemented):

```
D:/home/editor/src/main.c
------------------------
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TEXT_CAP 1<<15

typedef struct {
    uint32_t size;
    char ptr[];
} Text;

void load_file(Text text, char file_name[]){
    FILE* file = fopen(file_name, "r");

    for(int i = 0; i < TEXT_CAP; i++){
        fread(text.ptr + i, 1, sizeof(char), file);
        text.size += 1;
        if (text.ptr[i] == 0) break;
    }

    fclose(file);
}

void save_file(Text text, char file_name[]){
    FILE* file = fopen(file_name, "w");

    fwrite(text.ptr, text.size, sizeof(char), file);

    fclose(file);
}

void display(Text text){
    for(int i = 0; i < text.size; i++) {
        printf("%c", text.ptr[i]);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    Text text = *(Text*) malloc((TEXT_CAP * sizeof(char)) + sizeof(uint32_t));
    memset(text.ptr, 0, TEXT_CAP * sizeof(char));
    text.size = 0;
    load_file(text, argv[1]);
    display(text);

    return 0;
}
```

```
D:/home/editor/build.bat
-------------------------
@ECHO OFF

gcc -g -std=c99 ./src/main.c -o Murkrow.exe
```

console:

```
D:\home\editor>build.bat
D:\home\editor>Murkrow.exe build.bat

D:\home\editor>
```

I tried to use a bunch of print statements and found that any print statements after the memset() line doesn't do anything.

I also tried gdb and this was the output(I removed the copyright stuff from the output):

```
D:\home\editor>gdb Murkrow.exe

Reading symbols from D:\home\editor\Murkrow.exe...done.
(gdb) b 41
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4015b4: file ./src/main.c, line 41.
(gdb) b 42
Breakpoint 2 at 0x4015d3: file ./src/main.c, line 42.
(gdb) r
Starting program: D:\home\editor/Murkrow.exe
[New Thread 17524.0xf44]
[New Thread 17524.0x4844]

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x952228) at ./src/main.c:41
41              memset(text.ptr, 0, TEXT_CAP * sizeof(char));
(gdb) p text
$1 = {size = 3131961357, ptr = 0x61ff20 "\200"}
(gdb) n

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x7595f5df in wcstok_s () from C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll
(gdb)
```

Comment: `Text text = *(Text*) malloc((TEXT_CAP * sizeof(char)) + sizeof(uint32_t));` that's wrong: 1) Don't dereference the address returned by `malloc`. 2) Reserve space with the correct size, that's the size of the struct + the size of the flexible array: `Text text = malloc(sizeof(Text) + TEXT_CAP);` ... notice that `sizeof char` is always 1. Finally, if the size of the array is known at compile time then you don't need a flexible array member: `char ptr[];` --> `char str[TEXT_CAP];`, in this case `malloc(sizeof(Text));` is enough.

Comment: I tried ```Text* text = (Text*) malloc(sizeof(Text) + TEXT_CAP);``` and arrow operator in function definitions an seems to work now. I might implement reallocation when the text buffer fills up completely

Comment: MSVC gives one warning (possibly immaterial) for `for(int i = 0; i < text.size; i++)` *signed/unsigned mismatch*.

Comment: @DavidRanieri: Re “`sizeof char` is always 1”: So what? The number of sides in a triangle is always 3, but we would not tell students to replace `NumberOfSides` with `3`, because code for a triangle might later be adapted to code for a square or an arbitrary polygon. Using a name instead of a literal both helps explain the code and helps keep it adaptable for reuse. Text editors will not always work with `char`. They might be adapted to use `wchar_t`. Allocating a structure with a flexible array should use `struct Foo *p = malloc(sizeof *p + NumberOfElements * sizeof *p->Array);`.

Comment: `load_file` will probably not load a `save_file` file? I think you require it to be null-terminated? Which is not ideal for a text file. You probably want to check the return value of `fread`.